# clone or apply : which is "better"?

Tags: javascript, prototypal-inheritance

I want to create a series of objects that inherit or copy instance properties from a base object. This has led me to a decision about which pattern to use, and I wanted to ask your opinions about which method was "better".

```
//APPLY:
// ---------------------------------------------------------
//base object template
var base = function(){
   this.x = { foo: 'bar'};
   this.do = function(){return this.x;}
}

//instance constructor
var instConstructor = function (a,b,c){
   base.apply(this);//coerces context on base
   this.aa = a;
   this.bb = b;
   this.cc = c;
}

instConstructor.prototype = new base();

var inst = function(a,b,c){
    return new instConstructor(a,b,c);
}

//CLONE   
// --------------------------------------------------------- 
function clone(obj) {
    if (null == obj || "object" != typeof obj) return obj;
    var copy = obj.constructor();
    for (var attr in obj) {
        if (obj.hasOwnProperty(attr)) copy[attr] = obj[attr];
    }
    return copy;
}    

var x = {foo: 'bar'};

function instC(a,b,c){
     this.aa = a;
     this.bb = b;
     this.cc = c;
     this.x = clone(x);
};

instC.prototype.do = function(){
    return this.x;
}
```

they both achieve the same thing, namely unique instance properties based on a common template - the question is which one is more "elegant"

Comment: Does it really work to set `inst.prototype = ...` _before_ you've assigned `inst` equal to the function on the next line? Should that be `instConstructor.prototype = ...`

Comment: good spot - sorry - that was a typo

Answer (score 0, accepted):

OK, so i've given this some further thought - and the answer stems from the use case. Where clone is copying properties into a given scope, apply is changing the scope surrounding the property. The former is better for mixins, the latter for inheritance.

Answer (score 2):

By the sound of your questions it looks like you are looking for something akin to [Object.create](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/create). This function can be used to create a new object that has an object of your choice as a prototype.

```
//for old browsers without Object.create:
var objCreate = function(proto){
    function F(){};
    F.prototype = proto;
    return new F();
```

As for the comparison with the clone method, they do different things so you have to choose what is more appropriate.

Using **prototypes** will reflect changes on the parent object on the child objects.

```
a = {x:1};
b = Object.create(a);
a.x = 2;
//b.x is now 2 as well
```

You also have to be careful about using methods that have `this`. Depending on what you do you can have unwanted consequences if you use too much prototypal inheritance.

```
a ={
   x: 1,
   foo: function(){ this.x += 1 }
}
b = Object.create(a);
b.foo();
//a.x does not change
```

On the other hand, **cloning** clones stuff so you can be sure that the objects won't interfere with each other in any way. Sometimes this is what you want.

Comment: yup, been looking at that method too, but ran into some issues: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8073055/minor-drawback-with-crockford-prototypical-inheritance/8076515#8076515

Comment: Getting a handle on an object's prototype is finicky unless you can use things like the new getPrototypeOf or __ptoto__. Depending on what you want to do also copying the methods from the object to be cloned might also work.